# Выровнять текст по обоим краям

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Всем привет!

Как выровнять текст сразу и по левому, и по правому краю? Например, у меня есть текст:

```
Sample example - 111 abc

SomeExample Sample - 2222 abc
```

А нужно что бы было вот так:

```
Sample example -        111abc

SomeExample Sample -   2222abc
```

Comment: Может надо бы таблицей разместить такой текст,не divми!!!

Answer (score 2):

Поместите выравниваемый по правому краю текст в `span` с `float:right;`. Всю строку, в свою очередь, оберните в `div`.

Например:

```html
<div style="width:200px;"> 
    <p>Sample example - <span style="float:right">111abc</span></p>
</div>
```

Comment: это понятно , а что если у меня текст находится в отдельном файле , куда лучше не пихать html тэги потому что юзеры могут наговнячить , и там не одна строка и множество строк текста?

Comment: @S1lllver в таком случае, когда получаете текст из отдельного файла, расставляйте его в такие вот блоки <p>. Т.е. получили текст - расформатировали как нужно Вам и запихнули куда нужно Вам, а в этом вот файле html не держите, а генерируете его при выводе.

Answer (score 0):

Выровнять текст (без дополнительной разметки в нем) по обоим краям можно за счет `text-align: justify;`:

```css
.text-justify {
  text-align-last: justify;
  text-align: justify;
}

.text-justify:after {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}

.example {
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="example text-justify">
  Sample example - 111 abc
  <br/>
  SomeExample Sample - 2222 abc
</div>

<div class="example text-justify">
  <p>Sample example - 111 abc</p>
  <p>SomeExample Sample - 2222 abc</p>
</div>
```

[Или посмотреть код на jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gambala/2nwn5L1f/)

Comment: а можете пример соответсвующий оформить? просто немогу понять как в данном случае поможет text-align: justify;

Comment: Да, конечно - дополнил ответ. `:after` элемент нужен, чтобы корректно выравнивался многострочный (через <br/>) текст.